# VBScript (not VBA) adding Checkbox in Excel to specific Cell

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBScript that opens an Excel File called Test.xlsx and adds a checkbox.  It places this checkbox in cell A1.  I'm trying to find out how I can add this check box to another cell instead (for example, go to cell X61 and insert the checkbox there), here's my VBScript

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Test.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim chkBox

Set chkBox = objWorksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(0,0,0,0)
chkBox.Caption = ""

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objWorksheet = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: It's the `(0,0,0,0)` bit that determines where the checkbox is placed.  Replace the `0`'s with calculated position, based on range height and width properties

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.  My worry is that I have this check box in a loop.  Meaning that based on the number value of another field, that's how many check boxes I'll need to add in the cells.  So if I have to add 3 check boxes, first one starting at Cell X61, the next two would be X62 then X63 respectively.  So I'll have to figure out how to increment that calculated positions as well.  Thank you for help though, this gives me a starting point.